# Select records after ID

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which contains the following two fields (There are others, but they're irrelevant)

```
creation_time | object_id  
1325384907    | 75b31b2c-78e9-46b9-afc8-6d90c0df2ee6
1325388538    | c87734c9-5109-4956-a1cb-7e719ebb4549
1325430911    | 79fe7f41-4a73-4aa3-b1e4-68be0253d9ab
[...]
```

What I would like to do is select from the table, ordered by time, all objects after a certain object_id

So the sort of thing I'd want is a query like

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY creation_time ASC WHERE object_id > 'c87734c9-5109-4956-a1cb-7e719ebb4549'
```

Which should return `1325430911 | 79fe7f41-4a73-4aa3-b1e4-68be0253d9ab` (Being the next record after that object ID).

This is for a paging system (I.E. 'get results after'), the only information we have is the `uuid` so we can't just select `creation_time > x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE CREATION_TIME > (SELECT CREATION_TIME FROM MYTABLE WHERE OBJECTID='YOUR_OBJECT_ID_THAT_YOU_REALLY_KNOW' LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY CREATION_TIME ASC
```

Please be aware of LIMIT 1 because if subquery returns more than 1 result, the query will be fail

Comment: that's you need? it's really complicated to understand your question. Please if not is this, add a comment and i'll pleased in edit my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Creation_Time, Object_ID
FROM `tableName`
WHERE Creation_Time > 
        (SELECT Creation_Time 
         FROM `tableName`
         WHERE Object_ID = 'idhere')
ORDER BY Creation_Time
```

Comment: Please be aware with this answer, if subquery returns more than 1 result, the query will be fail. Also the user needs the order by on ASC, default for mysql is DESC.

Comment: @Leandro: If I am not totally wrong, default is `ASC` in all SQL-products.

Comment: Doh! I'm ashamed that I didn't think of this =(

Comment: @Leandro UUID's are, by definition, unique. In the incredibly rare instance we get a collision the record wouldn't be inserted since the object_id field has the `UNIQUE` constraint